# How to add the value of items (representing numbers) of two ListBoxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to add two integers (`X` and `Y`) from different ListBoxes and show the total in a Label or TextBox.

I've tried copying the code from answered questions and emending to suit my code, but still struggling.

```
Dim lblTotal As Integer 
Dim X, Y As Integer 
Const WasGo = 35 
Const Vacuum = 20  

' The item description from the ListBox are supposed to be Constants
X = extBox.SelectItems(0) 
Y = intBox.SelectItems(0) 
lblTotal = X + Y
```

Comment: Make a paste/copu of your code in your question AND format this text as CODE ! Sorry, I vote down for question's quality ! I can vote up later if you improve your question ;-)

Comment: Use that EDIT button to add your code to the original post.  Do not put your code in the comments...

Comment: ...and since you have ListBoxes, this implies that you can have more than one set of numbers?  You want to add up the "pairs" of numbers, then get the total of all those sums?

Comment: If you have read what constitiutes a proper question then you know that you need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That includes EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve, EXACTLY how you are trying to achieve it and EXACTLY what happens when you try. In your case, the first one is vague and the last one is non-existent. Do you want to add just one selected item from one `ListBox` and one from the other? What does that code do and how does that result differ from your expectations?

Answer (score 1):

ListBox has a SelectedItems property.  Assuming you have exactly one selected from each, this should work:

```
X = Convert.ToInt32(extBox.SelectedItems(0).ToString())
Y = Convert.ToInt32(intBox.SelectedItems(0).ToString())
lblTotal = X + Y
```

Few other tips/questions.

- I don't know what extBox, intBox, x and y are.  Make
  sure your names are well defined.
- Checking against the index of an array is good (If extBox.SelectedItems.Length > 0 Then), but then you need a way to handle that condition.  Maybe you need a prompt if nothing was selected
- What are you doing with an integer labeled lblTotal?  Is this getting displayed somewhere?
- I'm assuming your listboxes both contain a list of integers.

Comment: Looks like a C# answer.

Comment: @mary - i changed the array indexer to parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You don't use those constants in this code.
Convert the items to Integers so you can perform addition.
To display in a label's text property call `.ToString` on the Integer

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lblTotal As Integer
    lblTotal = CInt(extBox.SelectItems(0)) + CInt(intBox.SelectItems(0))
    Label1.Text = lblTotal.ToString
End Sub
```